# Neo4j: Count the number of neighbours with a specific label for each node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

As a sort of validation test, I want to count the number neighbouring nodes with a given labelB for every node with labelA and then return any labelA for each the number of neighbours is not equal to 2.

Basically, `parent:parent_name` should always have 2 connected nodes with have label `child_name`. How do I return the nodes for which this statement is False?

At the moment I am doing a very time consuming "match everything in neo4j" and then groupby and count in python Pandas.

Cypher:

```
MATCH (parent: parent_name) 
MATCH (parent)-->(child: child_name)
RETURN parent.id, child.id, 'child_name' as child_label, 'parent_name' as parent_label
```

Pandas post-processing:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['child_label', 'child.id']).apply(len)
result = grouped[grouped != 2].index  # returns pairs of child_label and child.id
```

I can't do this at scale. Finding neighbours is one of the main use-cases of graphs! There must be a way to do this!

Maybe using `UNDWIND` for each `parent_name`? If I use `count` under an `UNWIND` it simply counts the total, not the number for that node...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a general approach could be along these lines, finding any node with label `:LabelA`  that has not exactly two neighbours (regardless of direction of the relationship) with label `LabelB`

```
MATCH (n:LabelA)
WITH n,
     SIZE([(n)--(m:LabelB) | m ])  AS nodeCountLabelB
WHERE nodeCountLabelB <> 2
RETURN n
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to get the id of each `parent` node that has the wrong number of child nodes, along with a (possibly empty) list of its existing child ids:

```
MATCH (parent:parent_name)
WITH parent.id AS parentId, [(parent)-->(child:child_name) | child.id] AS childIds
WHERE SIZE(childIds) <> 2
RETURN parentId, childIds
```